# Dynamic Positioning of Data Fields in crystal report 13 update 18

Tags: asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I am using crystal report vs13 update 18.i have to set fields(columns) of report dynamically..i have found one solution here [Blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2011/09/07/dynamic-positioning-of-data-fields-crystal-reports-2008/)

But crystal report version 13 there is no option to change object Size and Position option.Pls suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you developing crystal reports using visual studio? Then switch to standalone installation,object Size and Position options are available in CR13

http://infosolblog.com/crystal-reports-with-dynamic-report-field-selection-part-2/

Comment: Thanks a lot...am using crystal reports using vs2015..can u pls provide 
 link to  download standalone version?

Comment: I think you should request you organization for licensed version https://www.sapstore.com/solutions/99013/SAP-Crystal-Reports-2013

Comment: Please try this http://ccm.net/download/download-2665-crystal-reports-2013